# How do I set up rsync between two of my own laptops on the same network?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, mac, rsync

I have two laptops, one running ubuntu and one running Mac OS X. How do I rsync from the Mac to the ubuntu machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set up sshd on at least one of the computers to allow access from the other. On the Mac it's at System Preferences, Sharing, Remote Login, on Ubuntu [apparently you just install openssh-server](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-openssh-server-installation-and-configuration/). Find out that computer's IP address (on the Mac, `ifconfig en1` if you're using Airport, `ifconfig en0` for the Ethernet connection). Then on the other computer run something like

```
rsync -Pvaz source_directory username@10.0.0.2:target_directory
```

where you substitute your user name for `username`, the relevant directories for `source_directory` and `target_directory`, the correct IP address for `10.0.0.2`, and [your favorite options](http://www.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html) for `-Pvaz`.

Answer (score 0):

There are surely ways to do that via a cron, but I think, its far better to install [Dropbox](http://www.getdropbox.com/)